# doxygen is not creating class for child interface

Tags: doxygen, idl, hal

I am creating document for `.hal` files using doxygen with enabling `idl` support.I have file called `A.hal` with following content.

```
/**
* A.hal
*/

interface A extends B {
     //some content
}
```

If i generate document for above file, i could able to see class name as **B** under class list (in doxygen output file i.e index.html). But, my expectation is **A** should come under class list. What is solution to achieve this? If `extends B` is not present, then **A** is coming in class list.

I am using following configuration.

```
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = hal=idl
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.hal
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which setting in your doxygen configuration file did you use different from the default settings (i.e. the output of `doxygen -x` for the more recent versions).

Comment: @albert doxygen version is `1.8.13`. Now i included conf details also.

Comment: The 1.8.13 version is already a bit older... the current version is 1.9.1, what happens when you use the newer version?

Comment: Probably best to create an issue in `https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=report-a-bug-or-issue.md&title=` with a bit a more complete example (i.e. some content filled in, so we can reproduce the problem).